# resttemplate does not retrieve the full data of a file from server

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

My project is using sping boot 2.3.3.RELEASE.

```java
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

I am trying to retrieve files from the server using `Resttemplate`.

My program works fine with small files. But my program does not obtain the bigger file correctly sometimes. The file size of one of the sample files is approximately 12.9M (It shows `13572529` by `ls -l`). The size of the file I downloaded always changes.

I can retrieve the file correctly using `curl`.

The code I used:

```java
    @Override
    public String downloadFile(String logId, String urlStr, String fName, String localPath) {
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String filePath = null;
        try {
            log.info("logId={}-Start to download, fName={}, data={}, filePath={}", logId, fName, urlStr, localPath);

            
            File dir = new File(localPath);
            if (!dir.exists()) {// Check whether the folder exists
                dir.mkdir();
            }

            filePath = localPath + fName;

            File file = new File(filePath);
            // Do not download the target file if it exists
            if (file.exists()){
                return filePath;
            }

            RequestCallback requestCallback = request -> request.getHeaders()
                    .setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.ALL));

            // Fetch data as stream instead loading all data into memory
            String finalFilePath = filePath;
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.execute(urlStr, HttpMethod.GET, requestCallback, clientHttpResponse -> {
                
                long contentLength = clientHttpResponse.getHeaders().getContentLength();
                log.info("logId={}-Content-Length in Response Header: {}", logId, contentLength);
                StreamUtils.copy(clientHttpResponse.getBody(), new FileOutputStream(finalFilePath));
                log.info("logId={}-Content-Length in Response Header: {}- file length: {}", logId, contentLength ,file.length());
                return null;
            });

            log.info("logId={}-download success, fName={}, ursStr={}, filePath={}, time cost={}ms", logId, fName, urlStr, filePath, System.currentTimeMillis() - begin);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("logId={}-download exception, fName={}, urlStr={}, e=", logId, fName, urlStr, e);
            return null;
        }

        log.info("logId={}-download success, fName={}, urlStr={}, filePath={}, time cost={}ms", logId, fName, urlStr, filePath, System.currentTimeMillis() - begin);
        return filePath;
    }
```

In the log, [the content length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773396/whats-the-content-length-field-in-http-header) from the response header is always correct, which is `13572529`. But the file length always changes.

I copy the code of `StreamUtils.copy()` to log the stream size.

```java
    @Override
    public String downloadFile(String logId, String urlStr, String fName, String localPath) {
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String filePath = null;
        try {
            log.info("logId={}-Start to download, fName={}, data={}, filePath={}", logId, fName, urlStr, localPath);

            
            File dir = new File(localPath);
            if (!dir.exists()) {// Check whether the folder exists
                dir.mkdir();
            }

            filePath = localPath + fName;

            File file = new File(filePath);
            // Do not download the target file if it exists
            if (file.exists()){
                return filePath;
            }

            RequestCallback requestCallback = request -> request.getHeaders()
                    .setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.ALL));

            // Fetch data as stream instead loading all data into memory
            String finalFilePath = filePath;
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.execute(urlStr, HttpMethod.GET, requestCallback, clientHttpResponse -> {
                
                long contentLength = clientHttpResponse.getHeaders().getContentLength();
                log.info("logId={}-Content-Length in Response Header: {}", logId, contentLength);
                copy(clientHttpResponse.getBody(), new FileOutputStream(finalFilePath));
                log.info("logId={}-Content-Length in Response Header: {}- file length: {}", logId, contentLength ,file.length());
                return null;
            });

            log.info("logId={}-download success, fName={}, ursStr={}, filePath={}, time cost={}ms", logId, fName, urlStr, filePath, System.currentTimeMillis() - begin);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("logId={}-download exception, fName={}, urlStr={}, e=", logId, fName, urlStr, e);
            return null;
        }

        log.info("logId={}-download success, fName={}, urlStr={}, filePath={}, time cost={}ms", logId, fName, urlStr, filePath, System.currentTimeMillis() - begin);
        return filePath;
    }


    public static int copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        Assert.notNull(in, "No InputStream specified");
        Assert.notNull(out, "No OutputStream specified");
        log.info("inputStream.................|{}", in.available()); // Always changes and less than content length. and less than byteCount
        int byteCount = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; // 4096 is the value of BUFFER_SIZE in StreamUtils.copy()
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            byteCount += bytesRead;
        }
        out.flush();
        log.info("inputStream.................|{}-{}", in.available(), byteCount); // in.available() is always 0. byteCount sometimes can get the correct value, `13572529`.
        return byteCount;
    }
```

The logs of this part after I tried several times:

```
inputStream.................|157672
inputStream.................|0-314056
inputStream.................|14320
inputStream.................|0-2206592
inputStream.................|32615
inputStream.................|0-13572529
inputStream.................|14320
inputStream.................|0-546655
```

`in.available()` shows the size of inputstream which is `clientHttpResponse.getBody()`, but why the size is always less than byteCount and content-length.

I read articles [spring-resttemplate-download-large-file](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-download-large-file), [download-large-file-through-spring-rest-template](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/download-large-file-through-spring-rest-template), [spring-resttemplate-large-files-contentlength-auto-changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311659/spring-resttemplate-large-files-contentlength-auto-changed), [download-large-file-from-server-using-rest-template-java-spring-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988370/download-large-file-from-server-using-rest-template-java-spring-mvc). I still do not find my solution and confused about the logs.

How do I get the right size for a bigger file? Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the contentLength of your HTTP call? - Also does you machine be able to process that huge file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with a couple of best practices (assuming you cannot upgrade your Sprint Boot from the old [Aug. 2020 v2.3.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.3.3.RELEASE), to a [v3.0.0+ release](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v3.0.0), currently [v3.2.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v3.2.1)):

- Use a [`BufferedOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) when writing large files to disk. That can reduce the number of write operations to the disk, which can be a bottleneck. I understand the article "[Download a Large File Through a Spring RestTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-download-large-file)" from [Eugen Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/about/) did use [`StreamUtils.copy`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-stream-utils), but  `BufferedOutputStream` remains a good practice when dealing with file I/O in Java, especially for large files.
- Add some error handling: make sure any exceptions during the file download process are properly handled, and consider implementing a retry mechanism in case of failures.
- Use [`SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html) and [setting `bufferRequestBody` to false](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html#setBufferRequestBody(boolean)): it prevents the entire request body from being loaded into memory, which can cause an out-of-memory error for large files. This is from the article you mentioned: "[Spring Rest template allows for efficient downloading of large files](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/download-large-file-through-spring-rest-template)" from Charlotte Dennis.
  Yes, `setBufferRequestBody` is deprecated since Framework 6.1, but it is still the right approach for your current Spring Boot version.
- Set appropriate timeout values for the connection and read operations to prevent the process from hanging indefinitely.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback;
import org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.util.StreamUtils;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FileDownloader {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public FileDownloader(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public String downloadFile(String urlStr, String localPath, String fileName) {
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String filePath = localPath + fileName;
        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);

        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
        requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(10000); // 10 seconds
        requestFactory.setReadTimeout(60000); // 60 seconds
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

        RequestCallback requestCallback = request -> request.getHeaders()
                .setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.ALL));

        ResponseExtractor<Void> responseExtractor = new ResponseExtractor<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                try (BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE))) {
                    StreamUtils.copy(response.getBody(), outputStream);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        try {
            restTemplate.execute(urlStr, HttpMethod.GET, requestCallback, responseExtractor);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Download completed. Time taken: " + (end - begin) + " ms");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred during file download: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return filePath;
    }
}
```

Consider also verifying the server's ability to handle large file requests, and make sure there is no intermediary (like a proxy or load balancer) that might be interfering with or truncating the file downloads.
And you could improve the `downloadFile()` function with, after downloading, validating the file (e.g., through checksums) to make sure it is complete and uncorrupted.